# How do I drop certain columns by colname for workbooks using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, operating-system, openpyxl

I am trying to understand how I can add to my current script where I'm able to make changes at sheet level. I want to be able to delete columns from the worksheets in my flat file here. For example, if a column is called 'company' I want to delete it so that my final wb.save drops those columns. I have multiple column names i want to drop from all sheets in the wb-

```
cols_to_drop = ['Company','Type','Firstname','lastname']
```

My code so far where I have managed to delete a specific sheet from a file and update colnames is below-

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os
column_name_update_map = {'LocationName': 'Company Name','StreetAddress':'Address','City':'City','State':'State',
                                  'Zip':'Zip','GeneralPhone':'Phone Number','GeneralEmail':'Email','DateJoined':'Status Date',
                                  'Date Removed':'Status Date'} 

        
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/hhh/Desktop/aaa/python/Matching"):
    if file.startswith("TVC"):
        wb = load_workbook(file)
        if 'Opt-Ins' in wb.sheetnames:
            wb.remove(wb['Opt-Ins'])
            wb.remove(wb['New Voting Members'])
            wb.remove(wb['Temporary Members'])

        for ws in wb:
            for header in next(ws.rows):
                try:
                    header.value = column_name_update_map[header.value]
                except KeyError:
                    pass
        
        wb.save(file + " (updated headers).xlsx")
```

This part of the code works perfectly and gives me the desired result. however, I'm unable to apply a dataframe logic like df.drop(['Company', 'Type', 'Firstname'], axis=1) since it is a workbook and not a dataframe

Comment: Do all your sheets have all the columns in `cols_to_drop`?

Comment: @not_speshal yes

Comment: This is similar to your previous question and the answer is the same: build a positional index from the column headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've tagged the question as `pandas`, you could just use `pandas` to read and `drop`:

```
for file in os.listdir("C:/Users/hhh/Desktop/aaa/python/Matching"):
    if file.startswith("TVC"):
        dfs = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name=None)
        output = dict()
        for ws, df in dfs.items():
            if ws in ["Opt-Ins", "New Voting Members", "Temporary Members"]:
                continue
            #drop unneeded columns
            temp = df.drop(cols_to_drop, errors="ignore", axis=1)
            #rename columns
            temp = temp.rename(columns=column_name_update_map)
            #drop empty columns
            temp = temp.dropna(how="all", axis=1)
            output[ws] = temp
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{file.replace(".xlsx","")} (updated headers).xlsx')
        for ws, df in output.items():
            df.to_excel(writer, index=None, sheet_name=ws)
        writer.save()
        writer.close()
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. A question i have is, why ' if ws in ["Opt-Ins", "New Voting Members", "Temporary Members"]:
                continue' These are the sheets I want removed from the original workbook and thats why i did wb.remove function

Comment: Exactly. So `continue` just does nothing to these sheets i.e. we don't save them

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-32-ff0746fd0efa>", line 8, in <module>
    output[ws] = df.drop(cols_to_drop, errors="ignore", axis=1).remame(columns=column_name_update_map)

  File "C:\Users\jtharian\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5465, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'remame'

Comment: It is "rename" and not "remame"

Comment: @notspeshal thank you. It works apart from 1 exception. in the first sheet it is giving multiple columns in addition to the final ones called - Unnamed: 13 Unnamed: 14 Unnamed: 15 Unnamed: 16 Unnamed: 17 Unnamed: 18. this is not in the second sheet within the wb only first one

Comment: Maybe you have some blanks in your original workbook? Just use `df.drop(cols_to_drop, errors="ignore", axis=1).rename(columns=column_name_update_map).dropna(how="all",axis=1)`